# Apps can't access network drive

Tags: networking, server, mount, encryption

I'm on 20.04 and trying to set up a server that I want to use for Plex and Sonarr.

I have an unlimited Google Drive mounted via rclone and that is encrypted and mounted via Cryptomator. The encrypted vault is mounted at `/home/administrator/desktop`.

The problem: Neither Plex nor Sonarr can access the vault.

Sonarr only gets to `/home/administrator` :

[image: Sonarr only gets to /home/administrator]

Plex gets to `/home/administrator/desktop` but my vault is grayed out:

[image: Plex gets till /home/administrator/desktop but my vault is greyed out]

The Google Drive + Cryptomator + Plex setup worked really well on my Mac, so I was hoping it would work on Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those file systems use fuse.

Fuse defaults to allowing only the user that mounted access, as many fuse filesystems doesn't have any real permissions.

The relevant flag to set is `allow_other` when mounting the fuse filsystem. In addition, you will have to edit `/etc/fuse.conf` and uncomment or insert a line containing

```
user_allow_other
```

for normal users to be able to specify `allow_other` on fuse mounts.

The [documentation for `rclone`](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) specifies a command line flag `--allow_other`, while [Cryptomator simply says](https://docs.cryptomator.org/en/latest/desktop/vault-mounting/#fuse-specific-options)

> If you want to apply FUSE-specific options on unlocking and opening your vault, you can add them to the `VaultOptions` of your vault. Check the `CustomMountOptions` on the `Mounting` tab.

More information can be found in the [fuse man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/fuse/mount.fuse.8.en.html)

Comment: Omg thank you so much!! That did it! For Plex at least. I was now able to add my Cryptomator vault to Plex and it was able to scan all my media. But unfortunately Sonarr still doesn't let me go further than /home/administrator. Do you have an idea on what to do?